# API for Encryption(Client) and Decryption(Server/Adapter) in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-studio, worklight-security

Please let me know

Is worklight is providing any API to encrypt data from client side and same data that can be decrypted from adapter(server) side?

Something like SecurityUtils which going to works on both(server and client)sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight does not provide such functionality.

Comment: Hope Worklight should provide this basic API ASAP. As searched over net, observed many developers are looking for it. Is there any reason behind this why Worklight not provided any API ?  Just curious to know.

Comment: Feel free to submit a feature request: developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help